# Passing single quote string to SQL stored procedure from VB.NET

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I am trying to pass single quote string from VB.NET to SQL stored procedure, but unable to get any result.

VB.NET code.

```
Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("pr_IncidentStatusByAssignment")
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure                
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SupportGroup", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "'Support Group South','Support Group Central'"

        cmd.CommandTimeout = 500
        cmd.Connection = con
        Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Using dt As New DataTable()
                sda.Fill(dt)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

SQL Stored Procedure code..

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[pr_IncidentStatusByAssignment]
@SupportGroup nvarchar(max)
as
Begin
    Select *
    from vw_IncidentDetails a
    Where a.SupportGroup in (@SupportGroup)
End
```

If I send a single value `"'Support Group South'"` from VB.NET code to SQL Server then there are results but not with multiple values.

Comment: Thats because your query turns into this `Where a.SupportGroup in ('''Support Group South'',''Support Group Central''')` which is unlikely to be what you want. You can't pass a list via a parameter like that, unless you want to call a string split function on it.

Comment: Also if you are going to pass a varchar parameter you should specify the size of it.

Comment: so should i create another function in SQL which will receive single quote string with multiple values and break down it and pass it to my main query..?

Comment: No, you should pass a table valued parameter

Comment: Look at the STRING_SPLIT function, depending on your version of SQL Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16